# selecting mutual numbers in database table

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

please friends this is a table for users who are friends so i want to select the mutual friends for user 1 and user 2. and the mutual friends are all the users marked in circle, i grouped each user with a specific color: here is my coding:

```
    SELECT * FROM friends AS f5
INNER JOIN 
((SELECT one FROM friends WHERE two =  '1') AS f1,
(SELECT two FROM friends WHERE one =  '1') AS f2,
(SELECT one FROM friends WHERE two =  '2') AS m1, 
(SELECT two FROM friends WHERE one =  '2') AS m2)
ON (f1.one  = m1.one AND f2.two = m2.two )
```

I want it to show the mutual friends of user 1 and 2 but it shows me an empty result when i run this query in SQL. please i need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the friends of one by doing a union of f1 and f2, then the friends of 2 the same way, then finally your inner join of those two results:

```
select a.* from 
(select one as f1 from friends where two = '1'
union
select two as f2 from friends where one = '1') as a
inner join
(select one as f1 from friends where two = '2'
union
select two as f2 from friends where one = '2') as b
on a.f1 = b.f1
```

Results:

```
f1
5
6
3
4
```